# Azure Databricks : How to filter a column with not like operator in data-frame?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have to exclude rows from dataframe where column **Justification** does not contains word **spare** in it :

```
"Justification":"WIWYNN | MSASM Spares | 21| MDM: 2520171"
```

I have tried following ways but nothing worked.(i am using spark python)

```
df= df.where(~ df["Justification"].like("%spares%"))
df = df.where(~(col("Justification").like("%spare%")))
df = df.where("Justification not like '%spare%'")
```

Results are returned with rows where **justification** column has **spare** word in it even though i have done negation.

> I want exact opposite result

Comment: try with lower function 
df.where(~(lower(col("Justification")).like("%spare%")))

Comment: It worked thanks. It didn't even crossed my mind to use lower. i though it is case insensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below code . Like is CaseSensitive. You need to use a Lower function before comparing.

```
df.where(~(lower(col("Justification")).like("%spare%")))
```